# Question about Thermocouple to digital convert output

Tags: adc

I have a MAX31855 Cold-Junction Compensated Thermocouple-to-Digital Converter. I have a question displaying the outputs on a LCD module. The FPGA board has a built into LCD module, so there is not much do to other than to tell it what to display for a given input. My trouble is figuring out what the input of the MAX31855 is going to be. I am reading the table, and it says the data comes in as a 14 bit SIGNED value. I understand signed notation, zero MSB is positive, 1 MSB is negative. What I don't understand is that the Digital Output is 0000 0001 1001 00 (100 in decimal) for the temperature in Celsius is 25+.

If I was trying to figure out a one to one relation, binary number [x] refers to temperature [y], how would I go about doing that?

Here is the datasheet, table 4 on page 10 is what I am referring to.

https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/MAX31855.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - 14-Bit, 0.25°C Resolution

Divide by 4.

Comment: ah, I did not know that is what they meant by resolution. Thank you.

Comment: Technically it means that you may also need to add a constant, but if you do the math you'll find that the constant is 0°C.